# div section not appearing on mobiles

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: desktop version]I have a `div` where I am displaying PDF's for learning purposes to students. The display of PDF's works absolutely fine for the desktop and the tablets versions.

My issue is on mobile and handhelds, the whole `div` shrinks vertically and displaying only a thin line. I want to rectify this but I am not aware of the responsive `css` implementations.

Can I have some insights regarding the same issue. I am having no clue how to rectify this for mobile views.

My code:

`<div id='viewer' class='pdf-viewer' oncontextmenu='return false' data-url='../admin/studyMaterial/underdevelopment_pdf.pdf'></div>`

and the `pdf-viewer` class:

```
.pdf-viewer {
  background: #909090;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What css properties does this div have?

Comment: var viewer;
        var url_url = $('#viewer').attr('data-url');
        
       $(function() {
          viewer = new PDFViewer($('#viewer'));
        });

Comment: This code is something that is being used in header file of the page. May be this can help

Comment: I have edited the question, please take a look

Comment: do you have a `viewport` meta tag in your `<head>` element?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> yes its there

Comment: Hmm. So, for some reason, it looks like the `<div>` is being squashed, unless I am misunderstanding the problem. Have you tried changing the `height` property to `400px !important;`? I would also try exploring other `height` possibilities like `vh` instead of a specified pixel height. I would also try checking to see what the height of div's parent elements are.

Comment: i posted your code into a snippet and all I got was a gray screen.

Comment: Try to use browser dev tool to watch in mobile viewport mode which CSS rule affects on the div

Comment: @rpivovar Hey thanks alot for this. It seems, making `height` to `400px !important;` works. But the issue now coming up is, only the first PDF is being displayed, and on scrolling the scroll bar, rest of the PDF's are not being displayed. What ammendments can we do for it. Actually rest of the pdf's are not being loaded in small screen other than the first PDF.